# How to run a Powershell function

Tags: powershell

I want to try using the script (I got it from another website) to set up the proxy server abcd.com.th 8080 with a exception list in our corporate PCs but I do not know to make it run. I saved it as a .ps1 file and run it but it seemed not working. Please help.

```
## http://woshub.com/using-powershell-behind-a-proxy/

function Set-Proxy ( $server,$port)
{
If ((Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -Port 
$port).TcpTestSucceeded) {
Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name 
ProxyServer -Value "$($server):$($port)"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name 
ProxyEnable -Value 1
}
Else {
Write-Error -Message "Invalid proxy server address or port:  
$($server):$($port)"
}
}
Set-Proxy abcd.com.th 8080

$ProxyExceptionList = 
"*.dh;*.gdmu;*.muarg;10.13.*;10.109.*;10.133.*;*.ehr2.com;
*.cldpaast1.ha.org.mu;cims-adi-app-cims-dmz-sit.ha.org.mu"

$ProxyProperty = Get-ItemProperty 
"HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
If ($ProxyProperty.ProxyOverride) {

$OldValue = $ProxyProperty.ProxyOverride

$NewValue = $OldValue+$ProxyExceptionList

$ProxyProperty | Set-ItemProperty -Name ProxyOverride -Value $NewValue

} else {

Write-Warning "List of proxy overrides is empty!"

}

## Enable Proxy Connection
##Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' 
ProxyEnable -value 1
```

Comment: you have to load the script `. .\path\to\script.ps1`, then call the function `Set-Proxy server port`.

Comment: `but it seemed not working` .. this is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in a script and run it, it will run the code and everything it needs will be executed.

The fact that it is not working means that this script does not solve your problem. So whatever the root problem you are having, this script is not the answer.

If you get an error after running the script, please write down the error so we can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As posted the script is broken, potentially, hence your failures.

Never copy/paste/run code from any location unless you try to know what it si doing, and doing so in an isolated test environment, to prevent/limit any negative impacts. Often you need to reformat the code, remove non-printable/invisible extra characters, random spaces, etc.

As noted, by the others, functions must be fully loaded/active before you can use them.

So, cleaning up this script a bit, to show what I mean (small refactor effort):

```
### http://woshub.com/using-powershell-behind-a-proxy/

function Set-Proxy
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    #>

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('snp')]

    Param
    (
        $server, 
        $port
    )

    If ((Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -Port $port).TcpTestSucceeded) 
    {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name ProxyServer -Value "$($server):$($port)"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name  ProxyEnable -Value 1
    }
    Else {Write-Error -Message "Invalid proxy server address or port: $($server):$($port)" }
}

Set-Proxy -server 'abcd.com.th' -port '8080'

$ProxyExceptionList = '*.dh;*.gdmu;*.muarg;10.13.*;10.109.*;10.133.*;*.ehr2.com;*.cldpaast1.ha.org.mu;cims-adi-app-cims-dmz-sit.ha.org.mu'
$ProxyProperty      = Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'

If ($ProxyProperty.ProxyOverride) 
{
    $OldValue = $ProxyProperty.ProxyOverride
    $NewValue = $OldValue+$ProxyExceptionList

    $ProxyProperty | 
    Set-ItemProperty -Name ProxyOverride -Value $NewValue
} 
Else {Write-Warning -Message 'List of proxy overrides is empty!'}

## Enable Proxy Connection
```

Why is this commented out??? - the code below is not valid and will not run.

```
##Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' 
ProxyEnable -value 1
```

If you want the to run, then the refactor is this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' ProxyEnable -value 1
```

***This should work as is as long as you are running this from say the ISE or VSCode, etc., but as noted by 'Abraham Zinala' feedback; you are going to need to fully qualify to the script tun run it from any CLI console.***